# How to dynamically render partial view inside _layout.cshtml for different areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've one layout page (_layout.cshtml) in main area,three areas called employee area,admin area & main area.respectively each area has its own partial view (side menu) called _employeeSideMenu.cshtml,_adminSideMenu.cshtml,_mainSidemenu.cshtml.
How can I render sidemenu in _layout.cshtml page according to area request.

I accepting something like that:

```
@if(Request from employee area)
{
    Html.Partial("_employeeSideMenu");
}
else if(Request from admin area)
{
    Html.Partial("_adminSideMenu");
}
else (Request from main area)
{
    Html.Partial("_mainSidemenu");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a perfect solution to this problem. Here it is-

```
@if(ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = "EmployeeArea")
{
    Html.Partial("_employeeSideMenu");
}
else if(ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = "AdminArea")
{
    Html.Partial("_adminSideMenu");
}
else (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = "MainArea")
{
    Html.Partial("_mainSidemenu");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current area name using this `ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]` and then apply result into your logic.